# How to add an object to application scope in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scope

We can set the request attributes using `Model` or `ModelAndView` object in Spring.

We can use `@SessionAttributes` to keep attributes in session scope.

Then how can I put an attribute in `application` scope in Spring, does spring has provided any annotation for that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically all that is needed to configure an application scope is to use the `ServletContext`, and you can do it in Spring as follows:

```
public class MyBean implements ServletContextAware {

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

}
```

`javax.servlet.ServletContext` could be even injected to your bean implementation as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void myMethod1() {
        servletContext.setAttribute("attr_key","attr_value");
    }

    public void myMethod2() {
        Object value = servletContext.getAttribute("attr_key");
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Francisco, as per spring documentation for @SessionAttributes - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html, there seems to be some restriction, can you please tell me what is the restriction and how it is different from regular session attributes. What is the correct way to store in session scope. please let me know if I need to create a separate question for this query.

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't get your question, what do you mean with restriction?

Comment: I will post a separate question with complete details about the issue with session, Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I have created this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026885/how-to-store-data-is-session-scope-in-spring, can you please take a look on it.

Answer (score 2):

When you mention about storing your model at application scope then I would conclude you wish to store it at the ServletContext level.
For doing that you need to make your controller implements ServletContextAware interface.

```
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;

// ...

public class MyController implements ServletContextAware {

private ServletContext context; 
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) { 
    this.context = servletContext;
     }
```

After getting access to ServletContext you can add it as a attribute

```
servletContext.setAttribute("modelKey", modelObject);
```

Kindly let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the spring you can get application scope by using @Autowired annotation

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;
```

Then you can access you element by using .getAttribute Method

```
Object someObj = servletContext.getAttribute("object",someObj);
if(someObj==null)
someObj = new Object();  //This will create new Object if it doesn't exists.
servletContext.setAttribute("object",someObj);
```