# How to store data is session scope in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, scope

I have created two object in session scope like this `@SessionAttributes({"userObj","simpleValue"})` in my controller.

I am adding a user object and String at these variables in my controller like this:

```
modelAndView.addObject("userObj", user);
modelAndView.addObject("simpleValue", "Hello World");
```

`User` class is a simple class with 2 properties `id` & `name`.

Lets say I created this in a controller called `Controller1` which shows `Page1`. I can see the data of my session variables in `page1`.

Now I created another controller say `Controller2` (this controller has no relation with `page1` or `Controller1`) which displays `page2`, now in this new page I am able to access only the single session attribute for `simpleValue`, I am not able to access `userObj`, I am getting empty result.

As per the [@SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html), it says:

> NOTE: Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond
>   to a specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently stored
>   in a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once the
>   handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore,
>   use this facility for such conversational attributes which are
>   supposed to be stored in the session temporarily during the course of
>   a specific handler's conversation.

So I have 2 questions here:

1) I am not able to understand why Spring allowing me to access the simple property but not the User object in `page2`.

2) The document also says we have to use either traditional `session` or `WebRequest`. I able to use the `sessison` and access the variables, but can someone please help me how to use `WebRequest` for storing objects in session?

This is the code that I am using:

**Controller1.java**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"mySessionAttr","userObj"})
public class Controller1 {

    @RequestMapping(value="/page1")
    public ModelAndView singleFieldPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("mySessionAttr", "Hello World");
        modelAndView.addObject("userObj", new User(1,"Scott"));
        modelAndView.setViewName("page1");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**Controller2.java**

```
@Controller
public class Controller2 {

    @RequestMapping(value="/page2")
    public ModelAndView singleFieldPage(HttpSession session) {
        return new ModelAndView("page2");
    }   
}
```

**page1.jsp & page2.jsp**, both have same code.

```
<p>Session variable : ${simpleValue}</p>
<p>Product's name is ${userObj.name}. The id is ${userObj.id}
```

This is my **User.java**:

public class User {

```
private int id;
private String name;

public User() {
}

public User(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

   // Setters & Getters
}
```

This is my configuration files:

**Spring based configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.examples")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**Web based configuration**

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);  

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the implementation of `User` class.

Comment: Buddy post the code of your controller 1 for post method, I have a strong suspicion that  you are doing status.setComplete();

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth, added my code, please check and let me know if any other details are needed.

Comment: @Mudassar, I have added the code that I am using, there is no `status.setComplete()` in my code, please check.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the problem with the user object lies on the fact that the class `User` does not implementing `Serializable`.

And regarding the `WebRequest`, it is basically an abstraction for `NativeWebRequest` and `AsyncWebRequest`, as you can see at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html):

> Generic interface for a web request. Mainly intended for generic web
>   request interceptors, giving them access to general request metadata,
>   not for actual handling of the request.

With that approach, [`WebRequestInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequestInterceptor.html) may be used for Servlets as well as Portlets requests as states the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequestInterceptor.html):

> Interface for general web request interception. Allows for being
>   applied to Servlet request as well as Portlet request environments, by
>   building on the WebRequest abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

@SessionAttribute is tied to a single controller and as such the controller is also in charge of managing that session context. If you want conversations use web flow.

Originally posted by javadoc

Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond to a specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently stored in a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once the handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore, use this facility for such conversational attributes which are supposed to be stored in the session temporarily during the course of a specific handler's conversation.

Although the term conversation is used here it is basically the conversation with a single handler (controller in this case) and not over multiple handlers. For such cases and better control use Spring Web Flow.