# spring executing the method after a predetermined time

Tags: java, spring

I have Spring controller with one method. When user run method, this method is not available to users for one hour

Below is snippet code:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void controlerMethod(){
    if(OverHour()){
        toDoSomething();
    } else {
        doNothing();
    }
}
```

I can't find a solution.
I do not have any idea what I should do.
Please a hint of solution

Comment: Can you just store the time it was last run, either in a static field or (if required) the dbs.  Then just compare against it when the method is called again.

Comment: Thanks Steve. But is there a way without using the DB(no permission) and static field(probably static is Bad:) ) ?

Comment: Store it in an application scope variable see this for reference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026353/how-to-add-an-object-to-application-scope-in-spring